# Add a fade effect to this image replacement jQuery snippet

Tags: jquery

I'm using this image replacement jQuery snippet so that when someone hovers over a thumbnail, another "main" image changes;

```
$('.circle img').hover(function () {
$('#main-image').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Is there a way to make the "main" images fade into one another when someone hovers over `.circle img` instead of them just switching?

Comment: you could try `.fadeout()` in jquery

Answer (score 0):

using `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` effect it can be done

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` instead of `hover()`
i.e

```
$('.circle img').mouseenter(function(){
//fadeOut

}).mouseleave(function(){

//fadeIn
});
```